# Stata: one title for multiple bar graphs

Tags: graph, title, stata

In Stata I try to create a graph that combines 9 bar graphs with the following code:

```
graph bar perc_not_like if x002_02a == 352 | x002_02a == 208 | x002_02a == 246 | x002_02a == 264 | ///
                           x002_02a == 578 | x002_02a == 752, title("Northern European Countries") ytitle(% of people that do not like immigrants) by(x002_02a)
```

The point is that I want only one title. What actually happens with the aforementioned code is that for each bar graph there is a title, which makes the graph a complete mess.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, generate each graph separately without the `title()` option.

After each graph generation, submit

```
graph save filename.gph, replace
```

(Change the filename to something different for each graph.)

Then submit the `graph combine` command, referencing each of the graph files you just generated, and include the `title()` option there.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved my problem:

```
graph bar (mean) perc_not_like if x002_02a == 352 | x002_02a == 208 | x002_02a == 246 | x002_02a == 264 | ///
                                  x002_02a == 578 | x002_02a == 752, ///
                                  ytitle(% of people that do not like immigrants) ///     
                                  by(x002_02a, title("Northern European Countries", span))
```

Comment: See `help by_option` for why.